# iOS distribution certificate revoked. cause any problem?

Tags: ios, xcode

While I try to create the iOS distribution certificate it says your account reached the maximum limit for distribution. if revoked one of the iOS distribution certificates. Is that cause any problem on the app that I have already the push to the app store with this certificate?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: (I fail to interpret `if revoked one of the iOS distribution certificates.` - can you check that sentence? In addition, please quote error messages (it says your account reached the maximum limit for distribution) verbatim into your question - standing out as a quote would be great.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we can create 2 **distribution certificates** from a **single** account, revoking one will **NOT CAUSE** any harm to launch apps on app store. YOU CAN CREATE ONE AFTER REVOKING ONE FOR yourself and edit the provisional profile also with new certificate that you created.

the only consequence is no one will able to launch the app from the revoked one  he has to get the new one along with he has to renew his provisional certi also

Answer (score 0):

Your App distribution uses exportMethod as Ad-Hoc, (e.g. Firebase Distribution), will no able to launch and install.

My terrible experience.